# how to show all the values including null while using range

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a project of `diagonistic bill centre management`, where user will select from date and to date, then all the test list will show with their number of request and total fee of request whether those test were requested or not between that specific range of date. If any particular test were not requested between that date range then for that test request no and fee will be zero, when I am specifying the date range only the requested ones are showing, not all the test list, can anyone help please how to also show the null values with date range,i used full outer join too but not working

The result should be like this,this is without range

[image: results]

updated result

[image: updated result]

Updated solved query

[image: Updated solved query]

Comment: I am going to take a guess that you are adding the date constraint as a WHERE clause, when you should be adding it to the LEFT JOIN to TestRequestTestName instead?  When you have a LEFT JOIN but then add a condition in the WHERE clause that depends on the values in the table you are OUTER JOINing to then you are effectively making an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Scsimon.i have tried using the where clause with TestRequestTestName left join clause but only the requested tests showed.i have solved the problem,have to add or RequestDate is null with between range.i have updated the query,thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, in this example I have used only two tables but you can expand it to more if you need to.

```
DECLARE @testType TABLE(    
TestID INT,
TestName varchar(128)
```

)

```
DECLARE @testRequest TABLE( 
TestRequestID INT,
TestID INT,
TestCost INT,
TestDate DATETIME
```

)

```
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (1, 'Bone');
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (2, 'Chest');
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (3, 'Head');
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (4, 'Infection');

INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (1, 1, 10, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (2, 1, 10, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (3, 2, 20, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (4, 2, 20, GETDATE())


SELECT 
TT.TestName, 
COUNT(TR.TestRequestID) [TestCount],   
ISNULL(SUM(TR.TestCost),0) [TotalCost]
FROM @testType TT
LEFT JOIN @testRequest TR ON TT.TestID = TR.TestID
AND TR.TestDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY TT.TestName;
```

Comment: Nanuz thanks for your reply,i have tried your query before but the output was same,only the requested test ones show,not all the tests,however i have solved it,i have to add or requestdate is null with the date range,then all the test shows whether they are requested or not with their corresponding request cose and no of request.i have updated the query.thanks :)

Comment: I think you should retest my query it returns all the tests. The ones with the values and the ones with nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version of the code below with results and more tests.

```
DECLARE @testType TABLE(    
TestID INT,
TestName varchar(128)
)

DECLARE @testRequest TABLE( 
TestRequestID INT,
TestID INT,
TestCost INT,
TestDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (1, 'Bone');
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (2, 'Chest');
-- These 2 test will no get a match and will be null
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (3, 'Head');
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (4, 'Infection');
INSERT INTO @testType (TestID,TestName) VALUES (5, 'Leg');

INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (1, 1, 10, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (2, 1, 10, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (3, 2, 20, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (4, 2, 20, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (4, 2, 20, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (4, 2, 20, GETDATE())

-- TestID 3 will get a 1 match here 
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (4, 3, 50, GETDATE())

-- TestID 3 will not get a match b/c of the date 
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (4, 3, 50, '2015-01-01')

-- TestID 4 will not get a match b/c of the date, null record 
INSERT INTO @testRequest (TestRequestID, TestID, TestCost, TestDate) VALUES (4, 4, 100, '2018-01-01')

-- TestID 5 will not get a match b/c none one scheduled it yet, null record 


SELECT 
TT.TestName, 
COUNT(TR.TestRequestID) [TestCount],   
ISNULL(SUM(TR.TestCost),0) [TotalCost]
FROM @testType TT
LEFT JOIN @testRequest TR ON TT.TestID = TR.TestID
AND TR.TestDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY TT.TestName;

/*  
Results:
    Bone        2   20
    Chest       4   80
    Head        1   50
    Infection   0   0
    Leg         0   0   
*/


-- To see null values run the query below
SELECT 
*
FROM @testType TT
LEFT JOIN @testRequest TR ON TT.TestID = TR.TestID
AND TR.TestDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE()

/*  
Results:
1   Bone    1   1   10  2017-01-16 20:17:31.030
1   Bone    2   1   10  2017-01-16 20:17:31.030
2   Chest   3   2   20  2017-01-16 20:17:31.030
2   Chest   4   2   20  2017-01-16 20:17:31.030
2   Chest   4   2   20  2017-01-16 20:17:31.030
2   Chest   4   2   20  2017-01-16 20:17:31.030
3   Head    4   3   50  2017-01-16 20:17:31.030
4   Infection   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   Leg NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
*/
```